# Is the output and reasoning correct for this problem?

Tags: c, command-line

Given the code below,  what's the output if we run the program prog4742 with the command `"./prog4742 6 5 8 6 9 4 2 6 64 200"`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        printf("%c", *(*argv+9));
        return 0;
}
```

According to me, the output should be 6. This is my reasoning for my answer:

1. The program starts executing, and the command-line arguments are passed to the main function.
2. The printf statement prints the character at the 9th position of the first command-line argument, which is *(*argv+9).
3. The first command-line argument is "./prog4742". When *(*argv+9) is evaluated, it refers to the character at index 9 of the string, which is '6'.
4. The printf statement prints the character '6'.
5. The program returns 0, indicating successful execution.

So, the final output of the program is "6". Is my answer and reasoning correct?

Comment: If you want to print the first character of `argv[9]` then you should use `argv[9][0]`. And if you want the ninth character of `argv[0]` then you should use `argv[0][9]`. When you do `*argv+9` that's really the same as `argv[0] + 9`. So your expression `*(*argv + 9)` is really the same as `(argv[0] + 9)[0]`. Which doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: How could the 9th caracter of string `"./prog4742"` be `6`? There is not even a `6` in that? Don't you have a compiler to test that? It might come in handy if you intend to learn C.

Comment: @js0110 Is it a question in an interview on a position of senior engineer?:) It seems you have to guess what the interviewer thinks about this.:)

Comment: @chrslg my understanding was that the code would be printing the 9th index value in the first command-line argument of string "./prog4742". is that not right?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow haha no, it's a practise problem I am doing to understand C better

Comment: Code like this isn't useful, not even for learning purposes IMO. There's no real purpose for code like this, other than for obfuscation and to confuse beginners. It's only learning purpose, I guess, would be to show students that it's possible to write ineligible code that doesn't make sense.

Comment: The only things you need to remember regarding arrays and pointers is that arrays can decay to a pointer to its first element; And that for any array or pointer `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is exactly equal to `*(p + i)`. Oh, and that you should generally never need to use the pointer-arithmetic syntax, only the array indexing.

Comment: That code IS printing the 9th index value of the first command line argument. You have that right (assumng that we count starting with 0, of course). `argv` is the array of arguments. `*argv` aka `argv[0]` is the 0th one, that is `./prog4742", as you said. So `*argv+9` aka `argv[0]+9`, is the same string, shifting 9 bytes to the right (in python, you would call it `argv[0][9:]`). So string `"2"`, with `"./prog474"` skipped. so `*(*argv+9)` aka `*(argv[0]+9)` aka `argv[0][9]` is the first char of `"2"`, that is `'2'`.

Comment: What I don't get is that you apparently understood the hard part, since you said "it is the 9th byte of 1st argument, that is of `"./prog4742"`. And then say, "so 6". How could it be "6"? Once you understood it is the 9th byte of "./prog4742", it should be obvious that it is not 6.

Comment: The important point, that is apparently tested here (it does not always reduce to that, be here it does), is that `*(a+b)` is just another writing of `a[b]`. So `*(*argv+9)` is `*(argv[0]+9)` which is `argv[0][9]`.

Comment: @chrslg I suspect that OP's "reasoning" here was generated by ChatGPT, which would explain hallucinating the "6".

Comment: @interjay Yes indeed. This is what I see with my students also (in maths). I explicitly allow them to use ChatGPT (I never try to forbid what I can't control), so no doubt; they tell me when they do. And it often end up with a very good reasoning, such as "we need to define a scalar product to use Gram-Schmidt to get a orthogonal basis, and then use it to project our function to get the closest function of the subspace", and conclude with a stupid answer "so, answer is 3.471", when what was expected was a periodic function...

Comment: @interjay so, yes, that was what I was trying to know: is this another instance of ChatGPT doing the hard part very well, and then fail miserably on the easy part? (which is quite normal when you understand what ChatGPT does: it reformulates answer obtained to similar question. And there were good reasoning in those answers. But then, since the exact same question is unprecedented, it fails on the application. So you can ask "what is the result of 2+2", and get a very accurate explanation on how to add things, concluded by answer "so, answer is 3.14".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*argv` is the same as `argv[0]`.  It points to the first string in the `argv` vector, which is `"./prog4742"`.  Then, `(*argv + 9)` advances the pointer by nine characters, so it points to the string `"2"` at the end of the same string.  It's equivalent to `&argv[0][9]`.  Finally, `*(*argv + 9)` dereferences that pointer, giving the character `'2'`.  It's equivalent to `argv[0][9]`.